# Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. Then f is not uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if I know what I have to do. I imagine that supposing that the opposite I should get any contradiction, but, how to choose $\epsilon$ and $x$, $y$, for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any $\varepsilon$ strictly between $0$ and $2$ will do. Then you have to wait until the adversary supplies you with a $\delta$ until you pick your $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, if I choose $x = \frac{2}{\pi}$ and $y = \frac{1}{\pi}$, then $|\sin(1/x) - \sin(1/y)| = 1 > 1/2.$

Comment: That works only for $\delta = 1/\pi$.  You need $x$ and $y$ to depend on $\delta>0$ with $0<|x-y|<\delta$.  Have a close look at the answer posted by @RRL ...

Comment: @Dr.MV Here is my attempt. Suppose that the claim holds. Then, choose $\epsilon = 1/2.$
Choose $x = \frac{2\delta}{\pi}$ and $y = \frac{\delta}{\pi}.$
Then, $|x-y| < \delta$. Ok, but,$ |f(x) - f(y)| = 1.$ Contradiction..

Comment: Good try.  But how did you conclude the last expression?

Comment: @Dr.MV You are right! I cannot conclude the end! Any suggestion? I am thinking and nothing...

Comment: See @RRl's solution.  It is solid.

Comment: Yes, it is a very good solution, is that I was thinking that would be any other example, more explicit... I don't know... But, thanks a lot for the discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Try $x_n = (\pi/2 + 2n\pi)^{-1}$ and $y_n = (2n\pi)^{-1}$.

What is $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)|$? What is $\lim|x_n - y_n|$?

Comment: $|x_n - y_n| \to 0$ and $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \to 1.$ What can I conclude?

Comment: In this case $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| = 1$ So given $\epsilon < 1$ you can never find $\delta$ no matter how small such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $x,y$  with $|x-y| < \delta$.  Whatever $\delta$ you pick, I can produce $x$ and $y$ with difference less than $\delta$ for which the difference in functional values is not less than $\epsilon$.  It is essential that $x_n$ and $y_n$ become arbitrarily close for this to prove non-uniform continuity.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of uniformly continuous is:

> **For every** $\epsilon > 0$ **there exists** a $\delta > 0$ such that **for all** $x$ and $y$, $|x-y| < \delta \implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

To negate the definition you have to bubble the “not” down through all the quantifiers and the implication:

> **There exists** an $\epsilon > 0$ such that **for every** $\delta > 0$ **there exist** numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$.

If you look at the graph of this function (or a computer's best approximation to the graph), you'll see that the values 1 and -1 are achieved infinitely often in every interval containing the origin.

Comment: I get your hint, but I am no seeing yet how to solve the problem..